# Firebase Query and database sturcture

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner in Firebase. To create a leaderboard-like list in my android app, I have set up a database on firebase, as shown below: [image]

Where all the userUIDs are under the "users" node, and under each userUID node are the user's data. I was trying to use the Query class methods to access 3 users having the top-3 highest "totalIMPs" value, and show their "name" on a Listview (list_TotalIMPs). To do this, I tried the following codes:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_totalIMPs=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1);
list_TotalIMPs=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_TotalIMPs);
list_TotalIMPs.setAdapter(adapter_totalIMPs);
Query query1=databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("totalIMPs").limitToLast(3);
query1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            adapter_totalIMPs.clear();
            adapter_totalIMPs.add("1");//for testing
            adapter_totalIMPs.add("2");//for testing
            adapter_totalIMPs.add("3");//for testing
            for(DataSnapshot postsnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                adapter_totalIMPs.add((String)postsnapshot.child("name").getValue());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Add in list: "+(String)postsnapshot.child("name").getValue(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Add in list: CANCELLED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    });
```

However, only the testing Strings "1", "2", and "3" appeared on my list, and also, there is no Toast showing. This means that a problem occuured in the "for" loop, and I guess it has something to do with the database structure. But I am having a problem figuring this out. Can someone help? Thank you so much.

(I was wondering if the datasnapshot is empty so that the "for" loop was never entered?)

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: You can test that last question by putting a breakpoint on the `for` loop and then starting your app in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the adapter beforing reading the data. Try setting your adapter in your onChange method:

```
Query query1=databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("totalIMPs").limitToLast(3);
query1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            adapter_totalIMPs.clear();
            adapter_totalIMPs.add("1");//for testing
            adapter_totalIMPs.add("2");//for testing
            adapter_totalIMPs.add("3");//for testing
            for(DataSnapshot postsnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                adapter_totalIMPs.add((String)postsnapshot.child("name").getValue());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Add in list: "+(String)postsnapshot.child("name").getValue(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            list_TotalIMPs.setAdapter(adapter_totalIMPs);
        }
        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Add in list: CANCELLED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    });
```

Comment: Still it didn't work :( I got the same testing data "1", "2", and "3"; nothing else; no toast.

Comment: @Rosario: that was my initial thought also (a call to `notifyDataSetChanged()` would be the better fix in that case btw). But since `1`, `2` and `3` show up, it seems that the adapter is getting notified already (I'm not sure how though).

Comment: Oops! Sorry about it, but I've just solved the problem. It was simply a bug in the databaseReference (which I didn't mention above) lol

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen (This might not be the appropriate place to mention this, but I liked seeing you in the Firebase in a Weekend course. Thank you for looking out for us here in SO)

Comment: I was about to ask you about the databaseReference. LoL, I'm glad you solved it :)